# Absolute positioned image missing on Safari

Tags: html, css, safari

My site [www.primaryself.com](http://www.primaryself.com) has a hero image at the top of the page which displays in chrome/edge/firefox, but does not display in in Safari.

I have narrowed it down to the css property position:absolute on the img tag, but not sure how to correct it.

I have tried removing the position:absolute style for the img tag, which displays the image, but it is not in the right position.

Here is the CSS

```
.BackgroundImage {
   position: absolute;        /* <-- removing this displays the image*/
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
}
```

Comment: [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it) -> No, you can't. Please add the code that is needed to reproduce your probelm so we can analyze it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add `display:block;` to the picture element 'BackgroundImage-Container'.